# Why doesn't this animation appear in DevTools Animations tab?

Tags: css, animation, google-chrome-devtools

I am attempting to work out how [Invision's blog](https://www.invisionapp.com/blog/inside-design-microsoft) animation works. Specifically the zoom and shading on the title image pictured below when scrolling.

I would have thought this would be a CSS animation, but it doesn't appear in Chrome DevTools 'Animations' tab.

[image]

**How does this animation work, and why doesn't it appear in the 'Animations' tab?**

Comment: It's a manual js animation via requestAnimationFrame, apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick look and here is what I came up with:

Let's start at the element `.post-hero`: this acts as a wrapper and has `position: fixed` to make the image more or less stay in place as we scroll.

Inside this there is the `.hero-bg` element which contains the background image itself. Note that this element has inline styles setting its `background` to `none`, but it has a `data-bg` attribute pointing to the background image itself. My guess is that on page load, some JavaScript is used to take this attribute and add the actual image.

The actual image is set as an `<img>` element, inside the `.backstretch` element inside `.hero-bg`. Now, the `.backstretch` element is where the animation itself happens: the opacity on this element changes as we scroll (to change the amount of shading), and there's a transform with 3D translation and scaling on the element changing as well. I guess this is done using JavaScript and a scroll event listener on the page.

Following `.hero-bg`, there is `.hero-overlay` which has a background color of `#252b33` and an opacity of 0.35 to provide the shading effect on the image, together with the opacity of the actual image changing as the page is scrolled.

Edit: if you right click the `.backstretch` element and select "break on attribute modifications", then scroll, you'll find that the attributes of the element are modified in a file called CSSPlugin.min.js. Googling this seems to point to CSSPlugin being a plugin for the [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap) animation library... I don't have experience with it myself but I know it's popular, others can probably confirm whether or not this is what's used to do the animation. My guess is that the animation is done using [GSAP CSSPlugin](https://greensock.com/CSSPlugin).